# Gulp 3.9 verion not compatibe with Node latest version

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, gulp, gulp-node-inspector

ReferenceError: primordials is not defined
The solution that worked is Upgrading the gulp version but it comes with another problem and that seems to be some changes in the v4.What exact version of node and npm works well with gulp 3.9.1? Is it compatible with node 17/18 version.

Comment: You are better off upgrading to gulp v4+ and asking how to migrate your gulpfile.js to v4.  There a couple of good articles about that: search for gulp and migrate.